# File Manager MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file

Hi there I have created a very simple file uploader:

Model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.WebPages.Html;

namespace BestPractices.Models
{
    public class AddPracticeModel
    {
public Guid folder { get; set; } 

[Display(Name = "Attachments:")]
        public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Controller:

```
   public ActionResult AddPractice()
        {
              form.folder = Guid.NewGuid();
              return View(form);

        }

    [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult AddPractice(AddPracticeModel formData, string FilePath)
            {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                     //Send To DB
                }
    else{

foreach (var files in formData.Files)
            {
                try
                {
                  if (files != null)
                    {

                      var dir = Server.MapPath("/Attachments/" + formData.folder.ToString());
                      if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
                      {
                          System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
                          var fileName = Path.GetFileName(files.FileName);
                          var path = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
                          files.SaveAs(path);
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          var fileName = Path.GetFileName(files.FileName);
                          var path = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
                          files.SaveAs(path);
                      }

                    }
                }

                catch
                {

                }

            }
    }
   return View(formData);
        }
```

So I'll explain exactly what is happening here: I create a Guid for this form and that Guid will become a folder where I will store files added for that specific practice. That way I can return the folders contents so people can download them and other options.

Now here is my View:

```
<div class="formBody">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddPractice", "Main", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id="myForm" }))
    {
      <div class="inputFields">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Files)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Files, new { type = "file", multiple = "true" })

            </div>
<div class="submitButton">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('isRealSubmit').setAttribute('value','True');" />
        </div>
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.folder, new { hidden = "true" })

                var dir = Server.MapPath("/Attachments/" + Model.folder.ToString());

                DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
                try { 

                <table>
                    @foreach (var file in d.GetFiles())
                    {
                        var dir2 = Server.MapPath("/Attachments/" + Model.folder.ToString() + "/" + file);
                       <tr>
                           <td><a style="color: red" href="/Attachments/@Model.folder.ToString()/@file" download>@file</a></td>
                           <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteFile", new { FilePath = dir2 }, new { onclick="var r = confirm('Are you sure you would like to delete?'); if (r == true){document.getElementById('myForm').submit();}", target = "_blank" })</td>
                           @*<a href="#" id="Delete">Delete</a></td>*@
                       </tr>
                    }
                </table>
                }

                catch
                {

                }
    }
</div>
```

So on post if there is more than 1 file added it will create a table of current items in the folder. However there are a few problems that were discussed, the first problem being that the form has to be posted in order for us to keep updated on new documents added to our table of current items in the folder. And then deleting items I had to read a new page called: DeleteFile which just gets the url and deletes the item then the main page is refreshed to show the current items in the folder. However, DeleteFile opens in a new page and the page is immediately closed. But that could be confusing to a user since they might see a page open and wonder why it closes so fast and call for support.

Is there a way I could make a file manager on the page that is updated without being posted through Jquery and Ajax. My knowledge isn't very strong in that field so it would be very helpful. And a way to delete the items without having to open a new page and then refresh our form.

Comment: **it will create a table of current items in the folder** What does this mean ?

Comment: So, to summarize, your question is "How do I use AJAX?"  That's a *bit* too broad for a Stack Overflow question.  Maybe take a look at some tutorials and examples online?

Comment: @Shyju if you look at the foreach statement in the view you can see a table of items.

Comment: @David I wouldn't say "How do I use AJAX" because I understand the concepts but I can't seem to find a way to update the table without having to post each time.

Comment: @MannySran: Update the HTML table?  What have you tried?  You've tagged the question with jQuery, and jQuery has a variety of functions for making a variety of changes to DOM elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use ajax to delete a file.

It might not be a good idea to show the server path where you are showing the files to the user (user can do view source and see your folder structure). You may simply use the file name (I hope it is unique) instead of the full path.

So inside the loop,

```
<table>
@foreach (var file in d.GetFiles())
{
    <tr>
        <td><span>@file</span>
        <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteFile", "Home", 
                  new {fileName = file, folderName= Model.folder})"  class="del">Delete</a>
        </td>    
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

And now listen to the click event on this link. Using jQuery

```
$(function(){

  $("a.del").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

    if(window.confirm("are you sure to delete"))
    {
      var _this=$(this);
      $.post(_this.attr("href"),function(res){
          alert(res.MessagePort);
          if (res.status === "success") {
               _this.closest("tr").remove();   //remove the item from the UI
          }
      });
    }

  });

});
```

Assuming you have an action method called `DeleteFile` inside your `HomeController` which accepts the file path and delete it.

```
[HttpPost]
public bool DeleteFile(string filePath,string folderName)
{
     var path = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Attachments/",folderName, fileName));
     if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
      {
          System.IO.File.Delete(path);
          return Json( new { status="success", Message= "Deleted successfully"});

      }
      return Json(new { status = "success", Message = "No file!!!!" });
}
```